# Can you write an LDAP query that returns accounts modified in the previous day?

Tags: ldap

I have a system that synchronizes from a master LDAP store. The synchronization process has gotten longer and longer as our directory grows. I had to stop syncing hourly, and moved it to an overnight schedule. But this results in more 'you have an account but I can't see it yet' problems.

I would like to add a parameter to the LDAP query that tells the system to only pull records modified in the past hour, and run it twice an hour; efficient and convenient. Unfortunately I can only find out how to filter on an absolute timestamp, such as `(modifyDateStamp>=201311210000.u)`, but not a relative time. The system we are using cannot build a dynamically created query, so I can't generate a new UTC timestamp every time it runs.

The answers in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1286526/how-do-i-retrieve-a-list-of-only-those-users-and-groups-that-have-been-added-sin/1286576#1286576) only mention using the UTC time, so I am pessimistic. Is there a solution?